# GStreamer rtsp Stream

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm currently trying to add an *rtsp* Stream to a  *Qt Widget*.

This is working:

```
gst_init (NULL, NULL);
GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch("playbin uri=rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/definst/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4", NULL);
```

Now I want to stream my local WebCam with the following URL:

> rtsp://192.168.178.45:554/11

It's working fine in *VLC Media Player*, but I dont get it to run in my application!

Does any one have an advice how I have to add the URL to the *GStreamer* pipeline?

Comment: The answer to this cannot fit in one page and quite a big piece of work. Start from learning paintEvent for instance and then go to OpenGL surface etc. and then learn what kind of video frames you get from GStreamer and figure out conversion to QImage and then go at the beginning of this note.

Comment: My Problem is not that i'm not able to display a rtsp Stream to a QWidget! Im using gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle and its working very good! My Problem is, that im not able to receive my specific stream via GStreamer.

Comment: And I can do that but the answer is like stripping it off of the project from my work to public github and posting a link for you here. It is not a short simple answer. To start with it is not really Qt question even though Qt involved. Learn if you can use Qt GStreamer API. I don't use it and don't deeply know that one: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/